# Обьект не добавляется в сессию

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Когда я обращаюсь к объекту так: `user.password`, то объект добавляется в грязный сет, но когда обращаюсь вот так: `user.__dict__['password']`, то объект не добавляется в грязный сет, следовательно в детектед и коммит. Но мне обязательно нужно обратится через `dict`

```
@router.put('/user/update_password')
def update_password(username: str, password: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = db.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
    user.password = password
    # user.__dict__['password'] = password
    db.add(user)
    db.commit()
    return 'yes'
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно.